# Reverse geocoding: function call to turn GPS coordinates to location name never executes

Tags: javascript, gps, geolocation

I am building an app that shows the local weather to the user. So far, I am able to grab the user's longitude and latitude coordinates using geolocation, but when I attempt to turn that into a location (e.g. New York, NY) via the function whose results get stored to geocodeLatLng, geocodeLatLng is undefined. I suspect that it has something to do with when the functions are called; does anyone know why?

```
window.onload = function() {

  var startPos;
  var geoOptions = {
    maximumAge: 5 * 60 * 1000,
    timeout: 10 * 1000
  }

  var geoSuccess = function(position) {
    startPos = position;
    document.getElementById('startLat').innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById('startLon').innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
  };

  var geoError = function(position) {
    console.log('Error occurred. Error code: ' + error.code);
    // error.code can be:
    //   0: unknown error
    //   1: permission denied
    //   2: position unavailable (error response from location provider)
    //   3: timed out
  };

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);

  document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = geocodeLatLng;

  var geocodeLatLng = function(startPos) {

    var latlng = {lat: document.getElementById('startLat').innerHTML, lng: document.getElementById('startLon').innerHTML};
    console.log(startPos);

    function address(results, status) {

        if (results[6]) {
          return results[6].formatted_address;
        } else {
          console.log('No results found');
        }

    }
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = geocodeLatLng;
```

You're not actually calling the function, you're assigning the function itself to `innerHTML`.  Call it by adding `()` at the end.  You're also missing the `startPos` parameter.

```
document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = geocodeLatLng();
```

Really though, you're going to want to make an asynchronous call to look up the location name.  How you do that depends more on how you're doing the lookup, which isn't specified here.